# Deserializing JSON using RESTSHARP

Tags: c#, restsharp

I have called an API request and serialized the response using RESTSHARP.
However, when im deserializing it's throwing the error

```
Error MSG Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

I know that the correct value has been serialized because in my console.WriteLine section it displays the auth token that i need to pull out.

Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var URL = "****/login/";
            IRestClient restClient = new RestClient();
            IRestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(URL);
            restRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            restRequest.AddParameter("application/json", "{\r\n \"UserName\": \"****\",\r\n \"Password\": \"*****\"\r\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse restResponse = restClient.Post(restRequest);

            if (restResponse.IsSuccessful)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Status Code " + restResponse.StatusCode);
                Console.WriteLine("Response Content " + restResponse.Content);
                JsonDeserialize();
            }
            
        }
        public static void JsonDeserialize()
        {
            var URL = "****/login/";
            IRestClient restClient = new RestClient();
            IRestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(URL);
            restRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            restRequest.AddParameter("application/json", "{\r\n \"UserName\": \"****\",\r\n \"Password\": \"****\"\r\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse<List<MySuilvisionAuth>> restResponse = restClient.Post<List<MySuilvisionAuth>>(restRequest);
            if (restResponse.IsSuccessful)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Status Code " + restResponse.StatusCode);
                Console.WriteLine("Response Content " + restResponse.Data.Count);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error Msg " + restResponse.ErrorMessage);
                Console.WriteLine("Stack Trace " + restResponse.ErrorException);
            }
```

Comment: What does the JSON look like? Are you even sure it's giving you JSON? It could be an error message.

Comment: the json response is 
{
"Jwt": "[Contains Base64 Token string]"
}
so the List<mySuilvisionAuth> has that in there as public string Jwt {get; set;}

Comment: in  the code here if (restResponse.IsSuccessful)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Status Code " + restResponse.StatusCode);
                Console.WriteLine("Response Content " + restResponse.Content);

it returns status code ok 
and {jwt: (authToken)}

Comment: What makes you think that JSON will deserialise into a `List<MySuilvisionAuth>`?

Comment: in my other projects ,i have always deserialized into a list 
i convert the json response into a c# list and then it always deserializes into there. Even the tutorial i followed showed this way of doing it, unless you have a better option ?  im just unsure on what could be causing this issue

Comment: That JSON isn't a list though. To deserialise into a list, it would have to be something like `[ {...}, {...} ]`

Comment: so if it is not a list, what would be the best way of deserializing something like this ?

Comment: Something as simple as `class Foo { public string Jwt { get; set; } }` would work with `restClient.Post<Foo>(restRequest)`